# Variables within class?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a class that looks like this :

```
var GridBox = React.createClass({
        loadLoadDataFromServer: function(modifier) {

        },
        handlePaging: function(modifier) {

          },
        getInitialState: function() {

        },
        render: function(){
            return (

            );
        }
    });
```

How do I add a variable within this class that all of the functions can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
var GridBox = React.createClass({
    a: 10,

    handlePaging: function(modifier) {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
});
```

Comment: That was my initial thought too.